# How can I scale the contents of a tkinter window up and down?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Well I need to scale (kinda like changing the screen resolution on your PC) the TkInter window up and down and I have checked like 200 answers and they are all for Python 2.0 so please do any of you guys have any help on this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Your question is almost unclear as it is asked by now.

Comment: Well I mean the objects in my window would get smaller but the window size would stay the same,

Comment: the features of tkinter are identical between python 2 and 3, with only a very few small exceptions. For all intents and purposes, you can assume there are no differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want. You can simulate it partly by setting up bindings that can grow and shrink the size of fonts as a window is resized, and you can double or halve the size of images. You can also have widgets like the canvas, text widget, and frames grown and shrink to fit. However, widgets in general won't scale. For example, checkboxes, radiobuttons, scrollbars, sliders will all stay the same size.